# Stack Bar in PHP with labels

Tags: php, javascript

I want to draw a vertical stacked chart using either javascript/php. I need a free/open source library for this. I have been using pChart ver 1.27d. It works well but the problem is that I am not able to get values on the top of each stack in the stacked bar. Please see the image below. It is exactly like this I want an output (exclude the line above the bars).

[Stacked Bar with Values on each stack](http://www.swiftchart.com/stackedmix_ex4.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are the [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/chart/) which can be used to do this very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Google Graph API, it's great for creating all kinds of graphs.

You enter all of the variables in to the URL, and it renders the graph for you:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 0):

Check [This](http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_bar6.php) taken
from the second link from google with `php chart`. Don't you feel ashamed?

Comment: Hey ! I had already tried out with many.... JpGraph is just one of them... PHPGraphLib, SwiftChart, RGraph, etc....
Please read my requirement. I need to display values in the middle of stack in a stacked bar. I was not able to locate this...